# How to override product model files in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, catalog, related-products

I am using Magento 2.3

I have override below core file.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php

To override this file I have created a new custom module in `app/code` directory.

I have created below files in my custom module:

> app/code/Custom/ProductModule/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Custom_ProductModule',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Custom/ProductModule/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider" type="Custom\ProductModule\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider" />
    </config>
```

> app/code/Custom/ProductModule/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
            <module name="Custom_ProductModule" setup_version="1.0.1" />
    </config>
```

> app/code/Custom/ProductModule/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Custom\ProductModule\Model\ProductLink;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\Converter\ConverterPool;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class CollectionProvider
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionProviderInterface[]
     */
    protected $providers;

    /**
     * @var ConverterPool
     */
    protected $converterPool;

    /**
     * @param ConverterPool $converterPool
     * @param CollectionProviderInterface[] $providers
     */
    public function __construct(ConverterPool $converterPool, array $providers = [])
    {
        $this->converterPool = $converterPool;
        $this->providers = $providers;
    }

    /**
     * Get product collection by link type
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param string $type
     * @return array
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $type)
    {
        if (!isset($this->providers[$type])) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__("The collection provider isn't registered."));
        }

        $products = $this->providers[$type]->getLinkedProducts($product);
        $converter = $this->converterPool->getConverter($type);
        $output = [];
        $sorterItems = [];
        foreach ($products as $item) {
            $output[$item->getId()] = $converter->convert($item);
        }

        foreach ($output as $item) {
            $itemPosition = (int)$item['position'];
            while(true) {
                if (!isset($sorterItems[$itemPosition])) {
                    break;
                }
                $itemPosition += 1;
            }
            $sorterItems[$itemPosition] = $item;
        }
        ksort($sorterItems);
        return $sorterItems;
    }
}
```

After creating this module I have run all commands in SSH but it seems the file is not overridden properly. I am getting below error in the front end:

```
Error filtering template: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor
```

Front end:

[image]

So What is the issue in my module?

Comment: You have  to do compilation properly.

Comment: As you want to modification on the public function you can use  plugin here

Comment: Are you saying that I have to run php bin/magento setup:di: compile command in SSH?

Comment: yes, right. Best way delete all files & folder from `gerenrate` folder  **exclude .htaccess** and run `php bin/magento setup:di: compile`

Comment: Do I have to run only compile or all of the commands(upgrade, deploy, indexing, cache)?

Comment: @AmitBera I have implemented your solution but still I am getting same error

Comment: error means you have to run upgrade then compile

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you have using **Amasty Shop by extension**. It may because of the cause of this error.

I  suggest that instead of using the Class override, use [**Magento plugin concept**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for your request.

As you want  customization over `getCollection()`  and this is a public function, so *you can use the **plugin Around method** for override the function output.*

Create `di.xml` at `app/code/Custom/ProductModule/etc/di.xml` and define the  plugin here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="product_link_collection_provider" sortOrder="1" 
        type="Custom\ProductModule\Plugin\CollectionProviderPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

NOw, create `CollectionProviderPlugin.php` at `app/code/Custom/ProductModule/Plugin` and write the code for plugin.

### Plugin class

```
<?php

namespace Custom\ProductModule\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\Converter\ConverterPool;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class CollectionProviderPlugin {

    /**
     * @var CollectionProviderInterface[]
     */
    protected $providers;

    /**
     * @var ConverterPool
     */
    protected $converterPool;

    /**
     * @param ConverterPool $converterPool
     * @param CollectionProviderInterface[] $providers
     */
    public function __construct(ConverterPool $converterPool, array $providers = [])
    {
        $this->converterPool = $converterPool;
        $this->providers = $providers;
    }    
   public function aroundGetCollection(
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider $subject,
           \Closure $proceed,
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
           $type)
   {
        if (!isset($this->providers[$type])) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__("The collection provider isn't registered."));
        }

        $products = $this->providers[$type]->getLinkedProducts($product);
        $converter = $this->converterPool->getConverter($type);
        $sorterItems = [];
        $output = [];

        foreach ($products as $item) {
            $output[$item->getId()] = $converter->convert($item);
        }

        foreach ($output as $item) {
            $itemPosition = (int)$item['position'];
            while(true) {
                if (!isset($sorterItems[$itemPosition])) {
                    break;
                }
                $itemPosition += 1;
            }
            $sorterItems[$itemPosition] = $item;
        }
        ksort($sorterItems);
        return $sorterItems;       
   }        
}
```

*After that you have to do compilation properly  and  Best way delete all files & folder from gerenrate folder exclude .htaccess and run php bin/magento setup:di: compile.*

Comment: I have implemented your solutions and It seems plugin is working fine but it is throwing an exception like "The collection provider isn't registered." in the product in admin.